# How to construct a common control group in two cohorts with different disease outcomes?

Tags: matching, epidemiology

**Question details:**
I have cohort data with a total of 100,000 participants. For some reason, I need to select 2000 participants as controls to construct a control group. I have 3,000 cases of disease A (stroke) and 6,000 cases of disease B (hepatitis). I wish to select 1500 cases of disease A, 1500 cases of disease B, and 2000 controls. It is required that these 2,000 controls have no statistical difference between the three variables of age, gender, and place of residence (8 different regions) for disease A and disease B (that is, similar to a matched case-control study, this is a matching process).

**Problems:**
I'm not sure if my current matching method is reasonable: I first randomly selected 1,500 cases from disease A and then matched them according to gender and region, matched the cases of disease B according to age ± 3 years within a specific gender and region, and controlled the final disease A and disease B to 1,500 cases. Then, I used one of the 1,500 screened cases (disease A or disease B) to accurately match all controls according to age, gender, and residence and obtained the final 2,000 controls.

**Expected to happen:**
Although I used T-test and chi-square test, as well as regression analysis to test the matching results, there was no heterogeneity among subgroups of age, gender, and place of residence. However, is there a more reasonable and scientific way to implement this process? After including other unmatched covariates, I find that their effects become weaker or no longer reasonable.